# node.js - utf-8 special characters are getting converted to ASCII ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to add trademark to my URL, but every time I use any (tested on trademark and copyright signs). For instance trademark sign:
`console.log('\u2122');`
shows in console: "`t`" instead of "`™`" .
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your console font doesn't know how to display that character.

```
console.log('\u2122');
```

Shows as ™ for me in my consoles (web + linux) ok - but probably wouldn't if my console font was something ASCII-based.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 default cmd terminal